# My k-means cluster analysis results are different in R and Python

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis, k-means

Recently I have been working on a segmentation project and initially I developed cluster model using the `kmeans()` clustering function in R. I am happy with those results and R created good differentiated groups for my data.

Now I need to migrate my code into Python 2.7. I am giving same and exact input data (scaling and removing outliers) for Python. But Python is not differentiating groups properly. I am using `KMeans()` function from scikit.learn. I am using a two variable exploration summary with cluster number wise.

Here is my R code:

```
library(cluster)
  set.seed(4)  #4 works
  clusters_result <- kmeans(dataset,centers=6, iter.max = 10,nstart = 20)`
```

R output:

```
cluster total_pages    photo_pages     n  rel.freq
1       1  57.7           4.4        19789 13.357138
2       2 243.5           0.5        18651 12.589013
3       3  24.2           0.1        41040 27.701093
4       4  16.4           6.6        14613  9.863452
5       5  66.6           0.1        37131 25.062604
6       6   7.4           0.2        16929 11.426701`
```

Python code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
model = KMeans(n_clusters=6,init='random', random_state=1, n_init=2, max_iter=10)
clusters_result = model.fit(scale(dataset))`
```

Python output

```
Out[1706]: 
   cluster  total_pages  photo_pages        n
0        0     49.7              1.0       25257
1        1     44.4              8.0       15862
2        2     55.4              0.0       20147
3        3     154.1             0.0       22454
4        4     43.9              0.0       38522
5        5     49.5              0.0       25911`
```

I've tried running the analysis multiple times with R code and I always got the same or very similar results. I repeated the analysis with Python, but the results are different.

Can someone help me here what is going on with the Python results?

Comment: maybe try with different `random_state` or even without any

Comment: @samorr hit at the heart of it; your `set.seed()` in R and `random_state` in Python are unlikely to be the same. `k-means` is not optimal, aka, it can get stuck on local minima. If you wanted to completely reproduce results across languages you'd need the same starting points. Or just don't set the seed and run it a bunch of times for each and you'll probably get closer results

Comment: Thank you Samorr and Ali for your comments. I have tried with out random_state option in couple times. But no luck... every time results are very similar to above python results...